# Zeros of $z^2 \text{cos}z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there an easy way to find the zeros of the function $z^2 \text{cos}z^2$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and the respective orders (multiplicities)? All I can think of is to find $f^{(1)},f^{(2)},...$ but then again that did not take me anywhere. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The multiplicities are the double of the multiplicities of $z\mapsto z\cos(z)$ and the zeroes of this function are all simple because $\cos(0)\neq 0$ and $\cos$ and $\cos'$ don't share zeroes. **Edit:** This is assuming you're looking at $z\mapsto z^2(\cos(z))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this function has a zero of multiplicity $2$ at $z=0$.

Consider now $g(z)=\cos(z^2)$.

Since $g'(z)=-2z\sin(z^2)$, there is no point $z\in\Bbb C$ where $g(z)=g'(z)=0$. Then, other zeros have multiplicity $1$

Comment: Thanks but how can you leave out $z^2$ and just focus on $cos(z^2)$?

Comment: Yes, the zeros of $f(z)g(z)$ are the zeros of $f$ and of $g$ together.

Comment: Never knew that. Is that a thoerem?

Comment: Well, I'd not say so, it's too obvious to call it a theorem.